Does mutability of type have an effect on scope of the variable?
I was playing around with global and local variables and noticed something different about lists and integers.
When I run the below code as expected two different local and global variables are created for integer types.
a = 10
def fun(a):
    a = a + 1
    print(a)
    print(id(a))

fun(a)
print(a)
print(id(a))


But when I do the same for a list something very weird happens. In the below code the variables inside and outside the function have the same id.
a = [10, 12]
def fun(a):
    a *= 3
    print(a)
    print(id(a))

fun(a)
print(a)
print(id(a))


That probably has an explanation I thought, and I would love to know the reason if anyone knows of course, but it get crazier when I make a very tiny change to line 3 and I can't put my finger why. The below code will now again have different global and local variables.
a = [10, 12]
def fun(a):
    a = a * 3
    print(a)
    print(id(a))

fun(a)
print(a)
print(id(a))


If anyone could explain why a list changes things and also why not using the short-form operator changes things it would be greatly appreciated! I'm running Python 3.10.6.
